# Best way to setup rails purchasing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, product

I have been having problems wrapping my head around setting up my rails store process. I have some models like songs and videos that I want to be able to be purchased. I created a purchase model that will keep track of what is bought by each user. I want to be able to display the user purchases on their download page. I thought that the best way to do this is to create a product model and create an association to songs or videos.

I have it setup so that the product model is created in an after create on the songs model. Here are my models

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :song
    has_many :purchases
end
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :user
end
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :product
end
```

I want to be able to loop through user purchases that are songs or videos on the download page @user.purchases that are only songs
@user.purchases that are only videos

I was thinking about do some where logic and place a category column on the product model, but thought this might not be efficient?

Answer (score 0):

I would store my relationship between Purchase and both Song and Video as a polymorphic relationship. Take a look a this:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, as: :itemable
  belongs_to :user
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :itemable, polymorphic: true
end

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :itemable, polymorphic: true
end

def User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchases
end
```

Now you can do stuff like this:

```
user = User.create
purchase = Purchase.create
video = Video.create
song = Song.create
purchase.items << video
purchase.items << song
user.purchases << purchase

user.purchases.first.items
=> [video, song]
```

You will need to set up your migration file correctly. Take a look at [this documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) for more information.